# Inserir dados Base de dados Tabelas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com dificuldade em inserir dados que tenham tabelas relacionadas.

```
$sqlinsert2 = "INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador VALUES(0,NULL,NULL,'".$MedicaValidade."',..
```

Actualmente os dados que estão como NULL são os campos relacionados com a Tabela.

tb_detalhe_trabalhador:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tb_trabalhador_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`tb_funcoes_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`MedicaValidade` date DEFAULT NULL,
`MedicaAnexo` longblob,
 (...)
```

Comment: Fica difícil responder sua pergunta sem termos o DDL das tabelas. Tem como editar sua pergunta com as mesmas?

Answer (score 2):

Existe um recurso chamado `mysql_insert_id()` que retornará a chave da inserção, atribua este recurso a uma variável e depois insira novamente na tabela relacionada.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você não esta conseguindo inserir os dados na tabela tb_detalhe_trabalhador pois a mesma tem duas foreign key (tb_trabalhador_id, tb_funcoes_id) sendo assim não será possível pois mesmo com default null ela deve estar linkada as tabelas referencias, ou pode ser por causa do valor zero (0) como id da tb_detalhe_trabalhador que vc esta inserindo que não é possível, dai nesse caso, por ser um campo autoincrement não é necessário passar nenhum valor.

Comment: Não acho que o problema seja o `NULL` nas chaves esstrangeiras. Pra mim o problema é no Id da tabela (valor zero).

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste local e vi que aceita valor null mesmo relacionado com outra tabela caso esteja com DEFAULT NULL como esta, e também aceita o (valor zero) e ainda assim faz o insert com o auto increment. Será que tem algo a mais que tenha além da dificuldade em inserir, pois que erro esta dando?

Comment: Não esta a dar erro nenhum. Mas quando vou ver os dados o tb_trabalhador_id aparece null. E não consigo fazer o INNER JOIN

Comment: @user3253195 agora não entendi. Pois no insert que mostrou esta inserindo o valor como NULL e assim não irá ter relação mesmo, sendo assim quando fizer o INNER JOIN não tem relação alguma, mas caso ainda precise que apareça na sua query tenta usar um LEFT|RIGHT JOIN. (ou tente melhorar sua dúvida)

Comment: Mas o problema do Left/Right Join é que só me mostra uma das tabelas. 
E com o INNER Join o resultado é em branco

Comment: Vamos lá: o seu problema é no `insert` ou no `select`? Se for no `insert` é só rever tudo que foi falado e possivelmente melhorar sua questão, mas se for no `select`, não tem como ter relação da `tabelaA` com a `tabelaB` sendo que o campo que faz essa relação esta com valor NULL, entendeu?

Answer (score 2):

Você deve ter `tb_trabalhador_id` já registrado na tabela relacionada antes de fazer essa consulta ou ela irá dar erro. Além disso, o valor de `tb_trabalhador_id` deve ser **exatamente** o mesmo que está na tabela relacionada.

> OBS: Sua pergunta está relacionada a Banco de Dados amigo, e não a **PHP** ou `Insert` (MySQL ou SQL seria melhor).